# Expanding nested sub nav items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have navigation with multiple levels of nested links and would like to be able to expand each level on click but I having issues with my jQuery I wrote for this and I'm not sure where to go next with it.

This is what I currently have:

```js
     subMenuAnchor = $('.menu-item-has-children > a');
   subMenuAnchor.append('<span class="aib plus-icon"></span>');
   $('.sub-menu').hide();
   subMenuAnchor.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.sub-menu').slideToggle(300);
    $(this).toggleClass('submenu-active');
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="menu-item-208" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-208"><a href="#" class="">Neighbourhoods<span class="aib plus-icon"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
    <li id="menu-item-203" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-neighbourhoods menu-item-has-children menu-item-203"><a href="http://salford.dev/neighbourhoods/neighbourhood-1/" class="">Neighbourhood 1<span class="aib plus-icon"></span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
            <li id="menu-item-210" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services menu-item-210"><a href="http://salford.dev/services/name-health-centre/">Name Health Centre</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-209" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services menu-item-209"><a href="http://salford.dev/services/name-surgery/">Name Surgery</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-204" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-neighbourhoods menu-item-has-children menu-item-204"><a href="http://salford.dev/neighbourhoods/neighbourhood-2/">Neighbourhood 2<span class="aib plus-icon"></span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
            <li id="menu-item-258" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services menu-item-258"><a href="http://salford.dev/services/name-surgery/">Name Surgery</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-259" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services menu-item-259"><a href="http://salford.dev/services/name-health-centre/">Name Health Centre</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Which produces this:

[image: screenshot of output]

I would like the `'Neighbourhood'` items to do the same as the `'NEIGHBOURHOODS'` item. What changes do I need to make to my jQuery to get this to work?

Comment: First of all you need another <ul> inside the nested <li>

Comment: @Cr1xus I'm using WordPress - I have set the menu up with the second lot of nested items but I can see now that the HTML for that isn't going in. I'll have a look at that and edit my question accordingly.

Comment: ok, I'll be happy to help you

Comment: @Cr1xus Updated to show the nested levels!

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720624/how-to-show-hide-specific-multi-level-nested-divs-with-jquery Let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is what you're looking for:

```js
subMenuAnchor = $('.menu-item-has-children > a');
subMenuAnchor.append('<span class="aib plus-icon"></span>');
$('.sub-menu').hide();
subMenuAnchor.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('li').find('.sub-menu').first().slideToggle(300);
  $(this).closest('a').toggleClass('submenu-active');
});
```

Working example:

```js
subMenuAnchor = $('.menu-item-has-children > a');
subMenuAnchor.append('<span class="aib plus-icon"></span>');
$('.sub-menu').hide();
subMenuAnchor.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('li').find('.sub-menu').first().slideToggle(300);
  $(this).closest('a').toggleClass('submenu-active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="menu-item-208" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-208"><a href="#" class="">Neighbourhoods<span class="aib plus-icon"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
    <li id="menu-item-203" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-neighbourhoods menu-item-has-children menu-item-203"><a href="http://salford.dev/neighbourhoods/neighbourhood-1/" class="">Neighbourhood 1<span class="aib plus-icon"></span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
            <li id="menu-item-210" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services menu-item-210"><a href="http://salford.dev/services/name-health-centre/">Name Health Centre</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-209" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services menu-item-209"><a href="http://salford.dev/services/name-surgery/">Name Surgery</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-204" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-neighbourhoods menu-item-has-children menu-item-204"><a href="http://salford.dev/neighbourhoods/neighbourhood-2/">Neighbourhood 2<span class="aib plus-icon"></span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
            <li id="menu-item-258" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services menu-item-258"><a href="http://salford.dev/services/name-surgery/">Name Surgery</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-259" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services menu-item-259"><a href="http://salford.dev/services/name-health-centre/">Name Health Centre</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. You were toggling all `.sub-menu`s on click. I limited it to only the first occurrence, going up to containing `li` (`.closest('li')`) and than applying to first occurrence of `.sub-menu` (`.find('.sub-menu').first()`). Happy coding!  :: }<(((*> ::)